How to set the position of the agent on a custom transporter
I created my own transporter and set the path it should travel. When captured by the transporter, the agent assumes a random position on the transporter but I would like to set its location explicitly.
I tried to configure the transporterControl and transporterFleet blocks but I did not find any settings for explicitly setting the position of the agent during capture. I have read the AnyLogic documentation ( https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/custom-transporter.html ) and there is no answer to this question.
